# Doctrine - own postgres function

Tags: database, postgresql, doctrine, dql

how can i call my own function stored in postgres DB, while i am selecting data throught

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('schema.my_function(id)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/099b770555a061cf/5ec062ad5f2e5323?show_docid=5ec062ad5f2e5323) shows a couple options.  If you just need to execute the function then [Raw SQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/native-sql) should work.  If you need to get results back then you may need another option.